# Xcode 10.2 still with Swift 4.2 Array of optional StringProtocol extension not compiling anymore

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4.2, xcode10.2

I've just updated to Xcode 10.2 and my formerly compiling extension can't compile anymore:

```
extension Array where Element == StringProtocol? {
    func joined(by separator: String = " ") -> String {
        return compactMap { $0?.description }.joined(separator: separator)
    }
}
```

The famous `Protocol 'StringProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` error now shows up...

Someone can tell me what happened? I have **not** migrated to Swift 5, just opened my project.

I have changed to:

```
extension Array where Element == CustomStringConvertible?
```

But I would like to understand why this changed... Any idea?

Comment: `CustomStringConvertible` is completely different than `StringProtocol`, so that change would modify the scope of your conditional extension significantly. Btw you should use `:` when checking protocol conformance, don't use `==`, since `==` should only be used when checking if the type is the same as another type. I cannot test using `Xcode 10.2`, but that change should resolve the issue.

Comment: I am aware that `CustomStringConvertible` is not the same as `StringProtocol` but for my usage, it works. The remaining problem is that using `:` does not work because I need `Element` to be optional... If I do so I get the `Type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'StringProtocol?'` (the same with `CustomStringConvertible?`...)